# Make Django form results editable

Tags: django

I have a form which users fill and all the results are displayed on another page as a table. How can I make the results editable in that page (table)? If you want to edit some row you can press something like an edit button which will make the row change the values from text to their respective widgets as in the form, so you can edit it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [django-jeditable](https://github.com/neskie/django-jeditable) which uses [jEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) jQuery plugin.